# Как выкладывать билд на Github?

Tags: github

Имеется: исходный код проекта на Python/PyQt5, и желание его выложить на GitHub. Но выложить хочу не только исходный код, а и билды актуальной версии. Как это лучше сделать?
Мне очень нравится организация репозитория вот здесь:
https://github.com/pyfa-org/Pyfa
Как создать такую же страничку с релизами?
https://github.com/pyfa-org/Pyfa/releases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На странице `releases` вашего репозитория есть кнопка `draft a new release` - там как раз и можно всю красоту навести - есть заголовок, поле ввода для текста с поддержкой `markdown` разметки и можно прикрепить файлы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Банально не видел кнопку "releases"...